# Is there such a thing as a temperature-controlled reflux column?

Tags: distillation

You know the deal - you're doing a distillation in the lab, but want a fraction that comes over at a very specific temperature. I find it very hard to control the temperature in my air-cooled reflux column. For anyone that's ever had to wrap their reflux column in aluminum foil, you know what I'm talking about.

Is there a piece of laboratory equipment that controls the temperature of the reflux column within a degree or so of an arbitrary setpoint? I'm thinking something like a condenser column (Liebig, Graham, etc) where the water (or other working fluid) that circulates through the jacket also passes through some sort of temperature controller so that the water/fluid keeps the walls of the condenser at a tightly controlled temperature. Any tips on where to find this kind of device?

I know of vacuum-jacketed reflux columns, but I'd prefer something where I didn't need to use a very long tube in order to separate close fractions.

Comment: Back in the day spinning band distillation stills had controls for the pot, column and head.

Comment: Yes, there are (were) electrical patches or bands, similar to thermal blankets in operating principle.